# How to skip a particular number when iterate over a range sequence number?

Tags: bash, loops, range, seq

Let's said

```
for i in {1..9}
do
  if test $i -ne 8
  then 
    echo $i 
  fi
done
```

If there a way to skip number 8 from this sequence `{1..9}` without doing the comparison?

**PS:** GNU bash, version 3.00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely do:

```
{1..N} {N+2..P}
```

Comment: Note the space between the two sets of brackets. Without the space this operation performs something else.

Answer (score 9):

damn... figure it out myself

```
for i in {1..7} 9
```

Answer (score 0):

just test if it's the value(s) you don't want and then continue which just finishes this iteration and goes on to the next one.

```
if $test == 8{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: A test like this is a comparison, which the author wished to avoid. In addition your if statement will fail with a syntax error since it is not valid shell code.